# How to calculate time complexity in Big theta

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, notation

I'm trying to calculate the time complexity in Big theta. Please help me out with this problem.

Q. There are two functions, **sub1** and **sub2**, which have time complexity of θ(4^n), θ(n^4 * log(n)) for each. If so, found out following two questions.

Q1. `for(i=1; i<n; i*=4) sub1();`

Q2. `for(i=1; i<n; i+=4)
        for(j=1; j<n; j*=4) { sub1(); sub2(); sub1(); sub2(); }`

Comment: Show your own attempts - at the moment there is no evidence that you are *actually* "trying".

Answer (score 0):

S1. The function **sub1** is called (log_4(n)) times. So the total time complexity is: θ(4^n log_4(n)) = θ(4^n log(n))

S2. The first loop happens n/4 times and the second one log_4(n) times. Each step takes  2*θ(4^n)+2*θ(n^4 * log(n)) = θ(4^n) by definition of θ. Thus, the total time is: n/4 * log_4(n) * θ(4^n) = θ(n) * θ(log(n)) * θ(4^n) = θ( n* 4^n * log(n)), by definition of θ again.